# How to do these 2 things in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: netbeans, ide, editor, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I recently switched editors from Netbeans IDE to Sublime Text 2. In Netbeans when coding PHP if I had a syntax error it would have an error icon at the start of that line.

**Sublime Text 2 doesn't seem to do this out of the box. What plugin do I have to install to get this feature?**

In Netbeans you can set up code templates. You will basically write for example something like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and call the template `jquery`. Then everytime you need to use jquery on a page you just tyoe `jquery` and hit `tab` and the script tag will be inserted in that spot.

**How to do this type of code template/shortcut in Sublime?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Php Syntax Check**

The SublimeLinter plugin supports automatic php syntax checking:

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter

**Template**

For javascript sources you can use the cdnjs plugin:

https://github.com/dafrancis/Sublime-Text--cdnjs

More generally, you can create your own templates. Here's one to accomplish what you'd like. Save this in the User's folder of your packages directory (go to Preferences -> Browse Packages) under the name "jquery.sublime-snippet"

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>jquery</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```